# Shortest line between perpendicular lines passing through a point

Tags: geometry

Given two perpendicular lines, $A$ and $B$, and a point $p$, I'm trying to find the points $a$ on $A$ and $b$ on $B$, such that $\overline{ab}$ passes through $p$ and is as short as possible.

[image]

I'm not very math-y, and my googling has failed to turn up a solution. Is there one?

Comment: Do we know any measurements or coordinates?

Comment: Have you taken calculus?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that if the lines $A$ and $B$ are walls of a hallway that goes around a corner, and the point $P$ is the inside corner of that hallway, the shortest possible distance $ab$ is also the length of the longest possible pipe or ladder that can be carried around the corner. And the steps in solving that problem include finding the points $a$ and $b.$ See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583707/intuitive-explanation-for-formula-of-maximum-length-of-a-pipe-moving-around-a-co

Comment: @me-- are you ok with the solution?

Comment: @me-- you can set as solved if you are ok

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found by **Pythagoras theorem** to evaluate the minimum of the lenth square of the segment

here is a **derivation of the solution**

[image]

here is **some graph of the solution** for $(X_P,Y_P)\in$ line $x+y=1$

[image]

Comment: Thank you I've fixed yhe typo!

Comment: The handwriting is not the easiest to read but the result agrees with https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1290503 (specifically, the intermediate step that says $x^3=AB^2$), so I'm reasonably sure it's correct.

Comment: Thanks, I'm preparing some graph to vizualize the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The equation of any straight line passing through $P(h,k)$
can be set to $$\dfrac{y-k}{x-h}=m$

$$y/(k-mh)-mx/(k-mh)=1$$

We need to minimize $$(k-mh)^2+(k-mh)^2/m^2$$

Now use $$2(a^2+b^2)\le(a+b)^2$$